# Is there a WinRT build of the Gracenote SDK that is universal?

Tags: gracenote

There is a build for Windows 8.1 but it was not build as a universal PCL.  Contacted support but they said to ask here, to get a response from the developers.

NOTE: by universal I mean, Windows Store universal, that work on WP8.1 and W8.1

Answer (score 0):

The latest [GNSDK for Mobile release](https://developer.gracenote.com/gnsdk) should support WP8.1. Please download the one with platform "Windows Phone 8."

Comment: nope, it does not work for Windows Phone 8.1 (they do have one for 8.0 but not 8) What I need is  just WinRT but build targeting the phone.

Comment: Just to make sure, you tried the latest sdk on 8.1 but it does not work. Correct?

Comment: Yup, WP8.1 apps don't work with libraries build for 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

Gracenote SDK is a native library. It is not an application. Just like any other third party library (like sqlite - check https://sqlite.org/download.html),
it porvideds winrt and windows phone libs. 
How do you build the library to run on phone and winrt both ? Can you post link from MSDN on how to do it ?. I dont think you can do this for libraries which has native component/s to it.

Gracenote window phone libs are built using visual studio 2012 and should work for both windows phone 8.1 and windows phone 8.0.

Comment: When you build a native library all you have to do is target WP8.1 and W8.1 seperately, using the shared project structure.  I should know, since I built a WebP SDK for WinRT 8.1. Retarget the library from 8.0 to 8.1, then right click the project in the solution explorer and click "Add Windows Phone 8.1" (should be there if your using VS 2013 with the  latest update). That's it! You should be able to build DLLs that work with Windows Phone 8.1 and, in the future, Windows Phone 10.

Comment: Alternatively, just create a new project using one of the "Universal" templates.  This will also give you three projects.  One called Windows, Windows Phone and Shared.  You should put all the code in the shared project and configure the target platform in each corresponding project (Windows and WindowsPhone)

Comment: Or, upload the source of the WinRT code to github and I can configure it to be universal and make a pull request.

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot upload source code. We will look in to this. Next release should have this update. Thank you for your feedback.